# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Use both OpenIDConnect and Custom Cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, openid-connect

I have an existing application that makes use of `Cookie Authentication`, and would like to add the ability to authenticate users using `Active Directory`. The current application uses Cookie based `authentication` and custom `authorisation` - roles in a database.

I am adding bits from example located here:

[Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET Core web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp)

When I run the application I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Cookies

What is the correct way to configure `OpenIdConnect` and `Cookie Authentication`.

**// STEP 1 Basic Cookie Auth**

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Auth";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/AccessDenied";
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(day/2.0);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // not accessible via JavaScript
                options.Cookie.Name = "login_token";

                options.TicketDataFormat = new CustomJwtDataFormat(
                    SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256,
                    tokenValidationParameters);
            });
```

**// STEP 2 OpenID Connect Auth**

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), "OpenIdConnect", "Cookies", true);
```

I am not able to find any examples using both `Cookie Authentication` and `OpenID Connect`. Is this possible? *Allowing users to login selectively using Active Directory authentication, or local authentication (details stored in local database).*

After changing the "Cookie" name, get's rid of the error message,
but breaks the local authorisation, e.g.

When a valid Username and Password is given, I typically
authorise the login.

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("login_token", token, GetCookieOptions());
```

Currently with OpenIDConnect configured `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`
remains false.

Comment: just question please, where to find the namespace from the 'AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp' method?

Comment: @Hasan namespace Microsoft.Identity.Web 

public static class MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilderExtension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error messages, it tell you that you have multiple Scheme which named cookies.

According to the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp Method [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebappauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapp?view=azure-dotnet-preview), you could find the third parameter name is the cookieScheme.

The cookie-based scheme name to be used. By default it uses "Cookies".

But you have already set this name at above, so you should use other one. For example: "ADCookies".

Like below:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"), "OpenIdConnect", "ADCookies", true);
```

Comment: I changed the cookie name to ADCookie (no error), but my standard authentication then fails to login. I assume that the cookies need to be shared else the login will not work.
Perhaps a working example of mixed login is what I need.

Comment: Do you mean you want both AzureAd and cookie authentication could work for some controller? User could use AzureAd  or cookie authentication to access the application?

Comment: Changing the Name of the Cookie got rid of the error. But wondering if it is even possible to Mix the two mechanisms. 

Currently I have not succeeded to get both to work that the same time. (e.g. Login with Microsoft and Login with my own mechanism). Seems like when I change the order STEP 1 and STEP 2, then I can get Basic Auth to work.

I assume AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp changes the cookie options too.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to mix two mechanisms.
I use MicrosoftIdentity authentication for access to administration web pages and cookies authentication for my APIs and SignalR hubs.

I use this in startup ConfigureServices

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie("CookiesApiScheme", options =>
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        // There is no redirection to a login page for APIs and SignalR Hubs, I just made a call to /Api/Login/SignIn with credential
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Api/Login/AccessDenied"); // Action who just returns an Unauthorized
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration); // By default scheme is "CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme"
```

And in API controller you can use something like this

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(Roles = Roles.ADMIN)]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "CookiesApiScheme")]
    public class DefaultController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

Based on this post: [ASP.NET Core 2.0 AzureAD Authentication not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45961781)

Answer (score 1):

The mixed approach is a minefield but the below is allowing use to Authenticate Users via IdentityServer4 using OIDC while authenticating the Application into AzureAD with Identity.Web to get tokens for Api calls.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "IS4Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("IS4Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "OpenID Connect", options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = "IS4Cookies";
    // Get IdentityServer configuration from appsettings.json.
    var config = Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServerOptions").Get<IdentityServerOptions>();

    options.Authority = config.Authority;
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.ClientId = config.ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = config.ClientSecret;
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Role);
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("email", "email");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("preferred_username", "preferred_username");
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRemoteFailure = context =>
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("/");
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    };
})
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureOptions")
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]{"sms.all" })
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use and it works, you just need to specify the configureCookieAuthenticationOptions and set the name inside there and you should be good to go, also I had to use lax for SameSite or it would not work for me.

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(identityOptions =>
/* {identityOptions.ClientId ="";}, // if you want to specify the options manually instead of Configuration.GetSection() call*/
    Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"),                    
    configureCookieAuthenticationOptions: authCookie => { // Setup SSO cookie                        
        authCookie.Cookie.Name ="Your.Cookie.Name.Here";// change name to hide .net identifiers in name
        authCookie.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;// make so client cannot alter cookie
        authCookie.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;// require https
        authCookie.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;// from external resource
        // verify options are valid or throw exception 
        authCookie.Validate();
    }
);
```

You may or may not need all of the authCookie values here, but it should get you started in the right direction!